# Why the error appears？a floating-point number multiply by a integer number

Tags: java

new coder
java environment

```
double pi =3.14; 
int a = 10; 
int b = 2; 
double z = pi*a*b; 
System.out.println(z);
```

I think the result is 62.8
but the real result is 62.800000000000004

I want to know ：why the error appears？
What could i read or which area should i study to dig in this question？

thanks a lot

Comment: Because not all floats/doubles can be exactly represented

Comment: try using BigDecimal

Comment: Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).